# iterate through many variables in a multi-termed lm model

Tags: r

Is it possible to go through multiple variables for x1 and x2? All the examples I could find were for x1 only `(y ~ ., data = dat)`.

I've included a hypothetical example. Say 'Growth' is plant growth rate, Mar - May is rainfall of the current year.  Marl - Mayl is rainfall from the previous year. For each city, I'd like to determine which month and lagged month is most correlated (R2) with plant growth rate. My actual dataset has 20 current months and 20 lagged months.

Perhaps something like: `lmList (Growth ~ X1 + X2 | City)` where the X1 calls for each of the current year months and X2 calls for each of the lagged year months.  Is this doable?

```
structure(list(City = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Buf", "Chi", 
"Det", "SanF"), class = "factor"), Growth = c(0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.9, 0.9, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 1.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2
), Mar = c(7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 
7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5, 7.5), Apr = c(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 
5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5), May = c(1.1, 
1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 
1.1, 1.1), Mar.l = c(12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 
12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6, 12.6), Apr.l = c(45L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 
45L, 45L), May.l = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L)), .Names = c("City", "Growth", "Mar", 
"Apr", "May", "Mar.l", "Apr.l", "May.l"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are after, but this code will iterate through each possible month and lag month, then return the `r.squared` from the model.

First off all, your data is not appropriate for a linear model because the months have the same values, so I've built some sample data that will work for this problem.

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(City = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Buf", "Chi", 
"Det", "SanF"), class = "factor"), Growth = c(0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.9, 0.9, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 1.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2
), Mar = c(3.73, 3.12, 1.55, 3.52, 2.15, 4.82, 3.6, 2.89, 2.05, 
4.12, 2.81, 1.48, 1.18, 6.2, 2.65, 2.48), Apr = c(13.42, 12.85, 
13.11, 13.37, 12.79, 11.81, 15.43, 13.78, 11.11, 15.61, 10.52, 
13.2, 13.42, 12.12, 14.58, 10.99), May = c(23.04, 20.73, 23.4, 
21.29, 16.62, 21.3, 20.9, 22.05, 22.15, 20.92, 21.26, 18.84, 
23.17, 16.47, 16.24, 17.42), Mar.l = c(11.82, 7.78, 9.23, 10.17, 
9.03, 5.83, 12.34, 9.85, 11.06, 10.01, 8.94, 10.2, 11.63, 6.99, 
7.69, 12.6), Apr.l = c(14.47, 19.08, 11.86, 22.44, 21.97, 17.65, 
26.77, 16.45, 17.54, 24.51, 21.29, 23.26, 26.33, 20.22, 22.25, 
15.79), May.l = c(34.64, 26.91, 42.76, 29.52, 30.3, 29.96, 9.65, 
20.07, 49.64, 37.07, 30.4, 28.41, 28.38, 34.39, 37.81, 20.19)), .Names = c("City", 
"Growth", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Mar.l", "Apr.l", "May.l"), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code:

```
# Get each unique month and lag month
months <- expand.grid(names(df[3:5]), names(df[6:8]), unique(df$City))

for(i in 1:nrow(months)){

  # Subset to city
  df_lm <- df[df$City == months[i,3],] 

  # First assign X1 and X2
  X1 <- which(names(df) == months[i,1])
  X2 <- which(names(df) == months[i,2])

  # Run model and get r^2
  model <- lm(Growth ~ df_lm[,X1] + df_lm[,X2], data = df_lm)
  months$r2[i] <- summary(model)$r.squared
}
```

Head(df):

```
     Var1  Var2 Var3         r2
1   Mar Mar.l  Buf 0.37860033
2   Apr Mar.l  Buf 0.79932606
3   May Mar.l  Buf 0.21933161
4   Mar Apr.l  Buf 0.86837821
5   Apr Apr.l  Buf 0.07531939
6   May Apr.l  Buf 0.06292426
7   Mar May.l  Buf 0.44959001
8   Apr May.l  Buf 0.08855373
9   May May.l  Buf 0.77037461
10  Mar Mar.l  Chi 0.31706634
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Actually, I needed the r2 for each city.

Comment: @ecologist55 In that case, just add `df$City` to `expand.grid()` and subset the data frame as you go in the `for` loop.  See edit above.  Hope this works better

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!!